# UV mapping with strange distorted texture

Tags: uv

The following image hopefully illustrates my problem better than a textual description:

[image]

A part of the mesh which is selected in the UV/Image Editor on the left is bent (the rim of a wooden wheel). 
I would generally expect textured faces to contain the part of the albedo-texture that is also displayed in the corresponding faces of the UV/Image Editor.

Consequently, from the way the texture is displayed in the UV/Image Editor, I expect the texture to have the wood grain aligned with the curve.
On the top-right Rendered Preview however, you see that the grain is radially aligned towards some vertex at the bottom of the rim.

Here is a Link to the Model:

[image]

What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: As this is Cycles render check that the texture you preview in the UV editor is the one selected in the Node editor. If they mismatch the one from the Node editor will be in the render

Comment: Thx. I should have mentioned that: it is the same texture.

Comment: Maybe double check that the selected UVs are for the faces you want. Try selecting just the front 4 faces in the 3d view and see if the same UVs are visible.

Comment: I wasn't so sure as it has more pronounced cracks in surface and looks like unpolished wood while one in UV editor is fine wood. Check if this is the same material. Check that you have one UV map and if not if you edit the one you see in render. What else to say. You can upload the blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ if you want others to look into it

Comment: @Brenticus: Thanks, checked that: the selected UVs are for the faces I want.

Comment: @MrZak I made sure the albedo texture used is the same.

Comment: The blend file you just uploaded is missing all of the textures. Can you try packing them with the file and then uploading again?

Comment: I might be about to figure it out ... there seems to be an issue with the normal map.

Comment: Just found that out as well. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your normal map is set to sphere mapping. Switch it to flat and you should be good to go. The albedo texture is fine, it's just that the normal map is so strong it makes it very hard to see.